# GridView: Columns.Insert() cause my data to vanish on postback, but Columns.Add() works OK?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, postback

I have a GridView that has several dynamic columns (I do not know how many at design time and it could be 0-12 columns, hence need for dynamic columns).  I have the columns in the grid and data bound to them - works great.  There are other standard, design-time TemplateField columns with TextBox controls in them.  These are bound with values that the user can edit.  The grid is posted back via a Submit button.

**My question is "Why does `gv.Columns.Insert()` cause all my `TextBox` data to be null on Postback, but `gv.Columns.Add()` works like a champ?"**

[Relevant SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306907/gridview-columns-add-vs-gridview-columns-insert-and-girdviewrow-findcontrol)

```
protected void BuildColumns()
{
    // The first column to begin to insert the columns in the GridView
    int columnIndex = 5;

    BoundField aoColumn = new BoundField();
    aoColumn.HeaderText = "New Column 1";
    gvMyGrid.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, aoColumn); // kills txtQuantity.Text on postback
    gvMyGrid.Columns.Add(aoColumn);                 // works fine
    columnIndex++;

    foreach (MyEntity my in _myEntityCollection)
    {
        BoundField myColumn = new BoundField();
        myColumn.HeaderText = String.Format("{0:d}", my.StartDate);
        gvMyGrid.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, myColumn);
        columnIndex++;
    }
}
```

I then go on to assign values to these BoundFields in the _RowDataBound method and all of this works great.  However, when I post back and try to reference some TextBox and they are all null.  And yes, I have the `BuildColumns()` call wrapped in if `(!IsPostBack)` on Page_Load.

**Of course I would like to use `.Insert()` so that the columns can go in the proper location and not at the end of the Columns array.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio bug that won't be fixed:

Read more about it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104994/templatefield-in-a-gridview-doesnt-have-its-viewstate-restored-when-boundfields-are-inserted).

Comment: Oh snap.  Not feelin' the love!